# Express router doesn't recognize mongoose model

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, routes

I'm working on a node.js app, and every time I run this code it pops up a reference error saying that Post is not defined. When I put the post route into app.js instead of submit.js, it works fine. That leads me to believe it's because submit.js doesn't "see" the model defined in app.js. I'm very new to web development, so it's probably something pretty basic that I'm missing.

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var submitRouter = require('./routes/submit');
var app = express();

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/posts");

//Mongoose Schema
var postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: String,
  date: Date,
  title: String,
  link: String,
  text: String,
  votes: Number,
  community: String
});
var Post = mongoose.model("Post", postSchema);

app.use('/submit', submitRouter);

module.exports = app;
```

**submit.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

router.post('/', function(req, res, next){
    var newPost = new Post(req.body);
    newPost.save()
      .then(item => {
      res.json(newPost);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        res.status(400).send("unable to save to database");
      });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post is not defined It’s because you don’t have mongoose schema defined in submit.js like you did in App.js.

You are creating an instance to Post using new Post but the Post doesn’t exist in submit.js

I would recommend you to put your schema in separate file and import it in submit.js

Create a folder called schema and inside this folder create a file name called PostSchema.js

PostSchema.js

```
   var mongoose = require('mongoose');
   //Mongoose Schema
   var postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
       username: String,
       date: Date,
       title: String,
       link: String,
       text: String,
       votes: Number,
       community: String
   });
   var Post = mongoose.model("Post", postSchema);
   module.exports = Post;
```

Import post schema in submit.js

```
  var express = require('express');
  var router = express.Router();
  var mongoose = require('mongoose');
  var Post = require('./schema/PostSchema.js');
  router.post('/', function(req, res, next){
      var newPost = new Post(req.body);
      newPost.save()
           .then(item => {
               res.json(newPost);
       })
       .catch(err => {
          res.status(400).send("unable to save to database");
       });
 });

 module.exports = router;
```

By the way, it’s not an issue with Express Router.

Comment: @PatrickBender you are welcome. Please do upvote and accept the answer so that it will help future readers